# What is thickness-shear mode technology?

Tags: resonance

Recently I've faced with the term **thickness-shear mode**.

Then I googled the term above, but I couldn't find anything useful to learn.

What is thickness-shear mode technology?

Comment: Some context would probably help.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Should I add context?

Answer (score 2):

They're pretty much what they sound like. Piezo resonators that operate in the shear mode. Obviously that mode of operation is much, much higher frequency than bending modes (MHz).

If the resonator is a disk, you're pushing (shearing) the top relative to the bottom without bending.

They're useful for [Bulk Acoustic Wave (BAW) viscosity sensors](http://www.sengenuity.com/technology.html) and other types of instrumentation.